# Shifting data in 2d array through shifted indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need to shift a 2D array field, i.e. I have a "previous_data" array which I access through shifted indices to create my "new_data" array.

I can do this in a nonpythonic (and slow) loop, but would very much appreciate some help in finding a pythonic (and faster) solution!

Any help and hints are very much appreciated!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import mpl

def nonpythonic():
    #this works, but is slow (for large arrays)        
    new_data = np.zeros((ny,nx))
    for j in xrange(ny):
        for i in xrange(nx):
            #go through each item, check if it is within the bounds
            #and assign the data to the new_data array
            i_new = ix[j,i]
            j_new = iy[j,i]
            if ((i_new>=0) and (i_new<nx) and (j_new>=0) and (j_new<ny)):
                new_data[j,i]=previous_data[j_new,i_new] 

    ef, axar = plt.subplots(1,2)
    im = axar[0].pcolor(previous_data, vmin=0,vmax=2)
    ef.colorbar(im, ax=axar[0], shrink=0.9)
    im = axar[1].pcolor(new_data, vmin=0,vmax=2)
    ef.colorbar(im, ax=axar[1], shrink=0.9)

    plt.show()

def pythonic():
    #tried a few things here, but none are working
    #-tried assigning NaNs to indices (ix,iy) which are out of bounds, but NaN's don't work for indices
    #-tried masked arrays, but they also don't work as indices
    #-tried boolean arrays, but ended in shape mismatches
    #just as in the nonworking code below
    ind_y_good = np.where(iy>=0) and np.where(iy<ny)
    ind_x_good = np.where(ix>=0) and np.where(ix<nx)

    new_data = np.zeros((ny,nx))

    new_data[ind_y_good,ind_x_good] = previous_data[iy[ind_y_good],ix[ind_x_good]]

#some 2D array:
nx = 20
ny = 30    
#array indices:
iy, ix = np.indices((ny,nx))
#modify indices (shift):
iy = iy + 1
ix = ix - 4
#create some out of range indices (which might happen in my real scenario)
iy[0,2:7] = -9999
ix[0:3,-1] = 6666

#some previous data which is the basis for the new_data:
previous_data = np.ones((ny,nx))
previous_data[2:8,10:20] = 2
nonpythonic()
pythonic()
```

This is the result of the working (nonpythonic) code above:
[image: nonpythonic working example of shifted data]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented a version of `pythonic` that replicates `nonpythonic` with some masking and index fiddling - see below. By the way I think the "new" indices should be the ones corresponding to the new array, rather than the old ones, but I've left it as in your existing function.

The main thing to realise is that in your attempt in the question, your conditions

```
ind_y_good = np.where(iy>=0) and np.where(iy<ny)
ind_x_good = np.where(ix>=0) and np.where(ix<nx)
```

must be combined, since we must always have pairs of `x` and `y` indices. i.e. if the `x` index is invalid, then so is the `y`.

Finally, if the indices are really all shifted by a constant factor, you can make this even simpler by using NumPy's `roll` function and taking a slice of the indices corresponding to the valid area.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import mpl


def nonpythonic(previous_data, ix, iy, nx, ny):
    #this works, but is slow (for large arrays)        
    new_data = np.zeros((ny,nx))
    for j in xrange(ny):
        for i in xrange(nx):
            #go through each item, check if it is within the bounds
            #and assign the data to the new_data array
            i_new = ix[j,i]
            j_new = iy[j,i]
            if ((i_new>=0) and (i_new<nx) and (j_new>=0) and (j_new<ny)):
                new_data[j,i]=previous_data[j_new,i_new] 

    return new_data

def pythonic(previous_data, ix, iy):

    ny, nx = previous_data.shape
    iy_old, ix_old = np.indices(previous_data.shape)

    # note you must apply the same condition to both
    # index arrays
    valid = (iy >= 0) & (iy < ny) & (ix >= 0) & (ix < nx)

    new_data = np.zeros((ny,nx))

    new_data[iy_old[valid], ix_old[valid]] = previous_data[iy[valid], ix[valid]]
    return new_data


def main():
    #some 2D array:
    nx = 20
    ny = 30    
    #array indices:
    iy, ix = np.indices((ny,nx))
    #modify indices (shift):
    iy = iy + 1
    ix = ix - 4
    #create some out of range indices (which might happen in my real scenario)
    iy[0,2:7] = -9999
    ix[0:3,-1] = 6666

    #some previous data which is the basis for the new_data:
    previous_data = np.ones((ny,nx))
    previous_data[2:8,10:20] = 2
    data_nonpythonic = nonpythonic(previous_data, ix, iy, nx, ny)
    data_pythonic = pythonic(previous_data, ix, iy)

    new_data = data_nonpythonic
    ef, axar = plt.subplots(1,2)
    im = axar[0].pcolor(previous_data, vmin=0,vmax=2)
    ef.colorbar(im, ax=axar[0], shrink=0.9)
    im = axar[1].pcolor(new_data, vmin=0,vmax=2)
    ef.colorbar(im, ax=axar[1], shrink=0.9)
    plt.show()
    print(np.allclose(data_nonpythonic, data_pythonic))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works! Now that I see the solution, it seems very obvious and straightforward!

Comment: Great! It's always easier with a fresh pair of eyes